# Samples of Android Calendar integration with OS 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I use the undocumented API's for calendar integration for Android OS 2.2.  Now that 4 is out, naturally the API's I use don't work!  I looked at the Android SDK regarding the calendar api's in level 14 but I'd love to see some examples of actually implementing the calendar API.

If anyone has any samples to share or a link to samples, please let me know.

Thank you.

P.S.  If someone has the reputation power to add a tag for android-sdk-4 that would help.  I was unable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example of using the new API in https://github.com/xamarin/Seminars/tree/master/2012-02-09-Top5FeaturesOfICS/CalendarDemo

There's a Seminar that features this on YouTube: http://youtu.be/CcdUq1AQfQ8?hd=1&t=2m45s

And there's also a write up of the API on here: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Introduction_to_Ice_Cream_Sandwich#Calendar_API

Comment: Hey chrisntr how can i use this CalendarContract class if my app was created using API level 8

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on the emulator. Try Settings -> Accounts & sync -> ADD ACCOUNT -> Corporate
Set up server as m.google.com and enable SSL.
It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone has any samples to share or a link to samples, please let me know.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Calendar/Query) that queries `CalendarContract` for events and loads them into a `ListView`.

Note that you probably need a production Android 4.0+ device to experiment with this -- certainly, it does not work in the emulator, as you can't actually set up a calendar account.